# How to add fixed tax automatically in invoice

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i have created a custom module to add stamp tax in invoice automatically . I have created a new page to enter stamp value and account in res.company. My problem is stamp tax does not add automatically to invoice. Any help please ??

account_invoice.py

```
from openerp import tools
from openerp.osv import fields,osv

class res_partner(osv.osv):
_name="res.company"
_inherit="res.company"
_columns={
"default_stamp_tax_account":fields.many2one('account.account',"stamp tax account"),
"default_stamp_tax_value":fields.float('stamp tax value'),
}
class account_invoice(osv.osv):
_name="account.invoice"
_inherit="account.invoice"
def create(self,cr,uid,values,context=None):

    stamp_account=self.pool.get('res.company').browse(cr,uid,values.get('company_id')).default_stamp_tax_account.id
    tax_value=self.pool.get('res.company').browse(cr,uid,values.get('company_id')).default_stamp_tax_value
    #pos_account=self.pool.get('pos.order').browse(cr, uid, values.get('company_id')).partner_id.property_account_receivable.id
    print stamp_account
    print tax_value

    #print pos_account

    if stamp_account:
        tax_line=[]
        tax_line.append([0, False, {'base_amount': 0, 'amount': tax_value, 'tax_amount': tax_value, 'name': 'Timbre', 'account_id': stamp_account}])
        values.update({
        'tax_line':tax_line,

        })

        print values
    return super(account_invoice,self).create(cr,uid,values,context)
```

Comment: Help me please i'm stuck with this problem

Comment: Can you look in the log for `tax_line` ?

Comment: [[0, False, {'amount': 0.6, 'tax_amount': 0.6, 'base_amount': 0, 'account_id': 392, 'name': 'Timbre'}]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find in the log a line similar to the following:

> > WARNING odoo9-demo openerp.models: account.invoice.create() includes unknown fields: tax_line

which tell you that `tax_line` field in not defined inside the `account.invoice` model.

If you did not define it in that model which is not according to the provided code above, you should use `tax_line_ids` to add the tax stamp to the invoice and be careful with invoice taxes added when calling:

```
super(account_invoice,self).create(cr,uid,values,context)
```

You can see that `taxes` are added to the invoice after calling `super` in [create method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L329) after calling `invoice.compute_taxes()`.

So you can use the same logic (compute_taxes) to add your tax.

- Edit
  Add you tax after calling super.

Comment: Not yet , i'm still stuck with that problem

Comment: How do you use it please ??

Comment: You need to replace `tax_line` with `tax_line_ids`.

Comment: Can you send me your code and the steps you follow ?

Comment: Ok , the problem when i replace **taxe_line** with **taxe_line_ids**  in the table of taxes it shows only my taxe instead of the taxe of product and my tax